# Summation at individual and overall level

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have something as

[image]

Looking for an output as

[image]

I was trying with RollUp, cube, Grouping Set but nothing seems to be fitting properly.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
declare @t table(

[Employee Name] varchar(50),Bucket int,
[Start Inventory No] int ,[Start Inventory Amount] int,
[No Of Promise to Pay] int,[Promise to Pay Amount] int)

insert into @t 
    select 'A', 0,10,10000,3,100 union all
    select 'A', 1,20,20000,7,500 union all
    select 'B', 0,45,90000,4,200 union all
    select 'B', 1,12,70000,6,600 union all
    select 'c', 0,16,19000,1,500 union all
    select 'c', 1,56,9000,10,2500

select 
    [Employee Name] 
    ,Bucket=case when x.rn= 11 then 'total' else Bucket end
    ,[Start Inventory No]= case when x.rn= 11 then sum([Start Inventory No]) else [Start Inventory No] end

from 
(select 
rn=ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition by [Employee Name] order by (select 1)), 
    *
from @t
GROUP BY 
        Rollup
        ([Employee Name] ,Bucket,[Start Inventory No],[Start Inventory Amount],[No Of Promise to Pay],
        [Promise to Pay Amount]))X where x.Rn in (1,6,11)

group by [Employee Name] 
    ,Bucket, rn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done with a pivot table on the client, not on the server.

If for some reason you do want to get to the second table from the first, I would do it as

```
select
  case when grouping(fake_column) = 1 then null else [Employee Name] end as [Employee Name],
  case when grouping([Employee Name]) = 1 and grouping(fake_column) = 1 then 'Gran Total' when grouping(fake_column) = 1 then 'Total' else cast(sum(Bucket) as varchar) end as Bucket,
  sum([Start Inventory No]) as [Start Inventory No],
  sum([Start Inventory Amount]) as [Start Inventory Amount],
  sum([No Of Promise to Pay]) as [No Of Promise to Pay],
  sum([Promise to Pay Amount]) as [Promise to Pay Amount]
from
  (select *, row_number() over(partition by [Employee Name] order by 1/0) as fake_column from @t) data
group by
  rollup([Employee Name], fake_column)
;
```

The idea is that you make each row unique by introducing a fake column, and include that column in the grouping, so that the original rows come out as 'grouped' results too (each 'group' contains one row due to the unique number).

Comment: The code has been changed substantially. See the previous version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52229650/1).